# Try use option Freestyle in script for Blender

Tags: python

I'm about to write a script that allows to make "true" the options (Freestyle in Blender):

[image: option FreeStyle in Blender]

Here is the python script I 'm writing to try to use options [Script python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXSWd.png)

```
import bpy

sceneR = bpy.context.scene

freestyle = sceneR.render.layers.active.freestyle_settings
linestyle = bpy.types.FreestyleLineSet
sceneR.render.use_freestyle = True
sceneR.svg_export.use_svg_export = True
freestyle.use_smoothness = True
freestyle.use_culling = True
linestyle.select_by_visibility = True
linestyle.select_by_edge_types = True
linestyle.visiblity = 'RANGE'
linestyle.select_silhouette = True
```

I found it in the window "info" Blender indicating each action done in Blender

my problem is that when I run the script it that nothing happens , and options (circled in red on the first picture) are always off or False .

Do I put the wrong way , is there a different way to activate this option in a script?

Comment: Please copy-paste the script into your question *in text*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, the use of `bpy.types.FreestyleLineSet` is wrong as this refers to the class definitions used elsewhere. The correct way to add a new lineset is `freestyle.linesets.new('mylineset')`, you also have a typo in `linestyle.visiblity = 'RANGE'`

A working version of your example is

```
import bpy

sceneR = bpy.context.scene
freestyle = sceneR.render.layers.active.freestyle_settings

linestyle = freestyle.linesets.new('mylineset')
sceneR.render.use_freestyle = True
sceneR.svg_export.use_svg_export = True
freestyle.use_smoothness = True
freestyle.use_culling = True
linestyle.select_by_visibility = True
linestyle.select_by_edge_types = True
linestyle.visibility = 'RANGE'
linestyle.select_silhouette = True
```

Comment: But i dont find a other typo for passe the option visibility to RANGE and take True for Silhouette ??

Comment: In your code you have `linestyle.visiblity = 'RANGE'` - with a missing `i` in `visibility` the silhouette setting should be right.